# Does GPS requires internet to get new Location in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing WP8.1 app for location track in background.And I am unable to get new location in background.
So i know that is it possible to find location in background using GPS or not in WP8.1. Because in a link i read that in WP8.1 not possible to use GPS in Background.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2370608

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My experience with WP says no need for internet, since I've used GPS while roaming (no internet).

It should however have positioning available based on GPS, cellular and wifi depending on accuracy settings...

Your title and description however are 2 different questions. Are you wondering about internet requirements, or how to get GPS in background?

Comment: My main query is how to get GPS in background in WP8.1

Answer (score 0):

You dont need internet for GPS. GPS works on location service. Location services works with Geo stationary satellite system that are different from Internet. So that you can use offline navigation with setting location services on.

Comment: Mainly i am asking about GPS in background in WP8.1, does GPS work or not in background in WP8.1

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for your app to run in background [as announced here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/02/22/what-s-new-in-location-tracking-api-for-windows-phone-8-0.aspx). You can run continuously in the background [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx).

There is also a list of features that can be used in the background [available on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662941(v=vs.105).aspx).

Most devices (if not all) have an AGPS (assisted gps) that uses metadata obtained via data connection to help locating the phone. If this data is not available (due to being offline) and the last gps data is rather old, locating will take much longer.

As background execution is still limited, your agent might get killed before the location finishes.

Comment: I am asking  about WP8.1 not for WP8.0.

Comment: Still applies for 8.1. Apis are the same since it both uses the RT geolocator.